# Puppeteer - how to return a result in page.evaluate within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, setinterval

i'm scrollig a page towards the bottom with puppeteer, when i press a key i want to exit from the function end return the results.

The script works almost, except i'm not able return values and the end of the script.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                                            headless: false,
                                            userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\johndoe\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"
                                        });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  });
  await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/groups/0000000/members',{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  
  
  let rawMembers = await page.evaluate(() => { 

    const intervall = 3000;
    let stop = false;
    document.addEventListener('keypress', e => stop = true);  //press a key to exit

    let results = [];
    let i = 0;
    let pageHeigth = 0;
    let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {

      if ((stop === false) && (document.body.scrollHeight > pageHeigth)){

        pageHeigth = document.body.scrollHeight  //save the current page heigth
        document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = pageHeigth;  //move the scroll to the end of the page (page visible size), this will couse new content to be loaded - virtula scroll)

        results.concat(pageHeigth);  //<--- it should be the results 

        timerId = setTimeout(tick, intervall);  //schedule a new timeout to repeat the function
      } 
      else
      {
        clearTimeout(timerId)
        return results;
      }

    }, intervall);
  });
  console.log('END')
  //await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a Promise and resolve it on timer termination (also, as mentioned in the other answer, `concat()` in not suited here, you can use `push` instead):

```js
const rawMembers = page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const intervall = 3000;
  let stop = false;
  document.addEventListener('keypress', () => { stop = true; });

  const results = [];
  let pageHeigth = 0;
  let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
    if (stop === false && document.body.scrollHeight > pageHeigth) {
      pageHeigth = document.body.scrollHeight;
      document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = pageHeigth;

      results.push(pageHeigth);

      timerId = setTimeout(tick, intervall);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      resolve(results);
    }
  }, intervall);
}));
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i've tried with a promise and works! but why works  without promise as well?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Do you have a variant without a Promise that also works (returns `results`)?

Comment: no, i'm wrong! it works only with the promise, like you said! thanks

Comment: Oh, ok) Good luck)

Answer (score 0):

`concat` method returns you a new array. It is not modifying the existing array. When you call the `concat` method you need to assign it to a variable. So this might solve the problem

```
results.concat(pageHeight) //instead of this

let finalResult = results.concat(pageHeight) // you need to do this
```

Other ways your `results` array always be empty because `concat` method does not modify the array.
Here's the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#return_value

And you need to return `finalResult` instead of `results` at the end.